# How can I fix the structure of Eclipse projects?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, project, structure

I've created a Maven project in Eclipse on one PC, pushed it to Git, then deleted the local files, and then cloned it from GitHub again.

However, now all those empty folders which used to house tests, resources, etc, are gone.

Should I be worried about that? Is there some Eclipse shortcut which ensures a project conforms to the expected Eclipse structure, or should I add those directories myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if these directories being missing will confuse Eclipse / Maven. I do know that, generally, build systems are smart enough to create missing directories.

However, from a Git point of view, you can force it to keep these directories by simply adding a file to them which is always present in your repository. Common examples of this are creating a "README" or a ".gitignore" inside the directory.

See this question for potential solutions:

[How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)

Comment: I know that, the thing is the directories had already been deleted... But I agree that a few missing directories shouldn't present an issue.

Comment: Right. So I would try checking out the project and building it. If it works, you're done. If it fails because of missing directories, create them, add placeholder files, and then commit.

Answer (score 1):

Add them yourself. The project structure you need is a characteristic from Maven, not from Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you. I'm just worried that somewhere, in some configuration file, I have these kinds of things written down, and that these situations where git wont cooperate by tracking directories too, might lead to inconsistencies...

Comment: git tracks files.  If you need certain folders, just have a placeholder file in it known to git.